# Place middle dots in place of spaces

Tags: rendering, dotfill, latin

Is it possible to get middle dots (·) in place of space like in classical Latin inscriptions?

As example, the following code …

```
\dotseparation{SENATUS POPULUSQUE ROMANUS}
```

… should appear like this “SENATUS·POPULUSQUE·ROMANUS”.

###### Edit 1

The goal is to treat the dotted spaces like normal spaces, with all the rules of hyphenation or breaking lines.

###### Edit 2

As I said in the previous edit, this dot-space should be treated as normal space and show the same behavior, especially regarding `stretchpars`. As example, with the solution given by Jasper Habicht below, the stretching isn’t respected:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l__dotseparation_words_seq
\NewDocumentCommand{\dotseparation}{ m }{
    \regex_split:nnN { \s } { #1 } \l__dotseparation_words_seq
    \seq_use:Nn \l__dotseparation_words_seq { \char"2E31 \hskip0pt } 
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}


\begin{center}
  \null
  \vfill

  \newenvironment{stretchpars}
  {\par\setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt}}
  {\par}


  \begin{minipage}{6.8cm}
    \begin{stretchpars}
      CUI DONO LEPIDUM NOUUM LIBELLUM

      ARIDA MODO PUMICE EXPOLITUM ?

      CORNELI, TIBI NAMQUE TU SOLEBAS

      MEAS ESSE ALIQUID PUTARE NUGAS
    \end{stretchpars}
  \end{minipage}

  \vspace{1cm}

  \begin{minipage}{6.8cm}
    \begin{stretchpars}
      \dotseparation{CUI DONO LEPIDUM NOUUM LIBELLUM}

      \dotseparation{ARIDA MODO PUMICE EXPOLITUM ?}

      \dotseparation{CORNELI, TIBI NAMQUE TU SOLEBAS}

      \dotseparation{MEAS ESSE ALIQUID PUTARE NUGAS}
    \end{stretchpars}
  \end{minipage}

  \vfill
  \null
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

[image: Rendering]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l__dotseparation_words_seq
\NewDocumentCommand{\dotseparation}{ m }{
    \regex_split:nnN { \s } { #1 } \l__dotseparation_words_seq
    \seq_use:Nn \l__dotseparation_words_seq { \char"00B7\hskip0pt } 
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\dotseparation{SENATUS POPULUSQUE ROMANUS}

\dotseparation{URBS ROMA A COLONIIS CIRCUM VADUM IN FLUMINE TIBERE QUADRIVIUM 
    COMMERCII MERCATURAEQUE PROFECTA EST.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Noto Serif has a glyph for U+2E31 "WORD SEPARATOR MIDDLE DOT" which might be the proper codepoint here, you could also add some glue to allow for some stretchability (thanks to barbara beeton):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l__dotseparation_words_seq
\NewDocumentCommand{\dotseparation}{ m }{
    \regex_split:nnN { \s } { #1 } \l__dotseparation_words_seq
    \seq_use:Nn \l__dotseparation_words_seq { \hspace{0pt plus .05em} \char"2E31 \hspace{0pt plus .05em} } 
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newenvironment{stretchpars}
    {\par\setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt}}
    {\par}
    

\begin{document}

\dotseparation{SENATUS POPULUSQUE ROMANUS}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{6.8cm}
    \begin{stretchpars}
        \dotseparation{CUI DONO LEPIDUM NOUUM LIBELLUM}
        
        \dotseparation{ARIDA MODO PUMICE EXPOLITUM ?}
        
        \dotseparation{CORNELI, TIBI NAMQUE TU SOLEBAS}
        
        \dotseparation{MEAS ESSE ALIQUID PUTARE NUGAS}
    \end{stretchpars}
\end{minipage}
  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There are also `U+2E31 "WORD SEPARATOR MIDDLE DOT"` and `U+2027 "HYPHENATION POINT"`, which might be more sensible codepoints here. However, only few fonts contain these.

Comment: Well… as y said in the 2d edit, this solution didn’t really remain the behavior of normal space especially in `stretchpars`.

Comment: How about trying `\hspace{0pt plus .05em}` before and after the dot?

Comment: @fauve Well, "behavior of normal space" is a term that needs a proper definition. In my first answer I focused on hyphenation and breakability as you did in your original question. My edit now allows for stretchability, but I am sure that there are still some areas where even this solution is different from the behavior of a space. (Take, for example, the situation where such a dot happens to be at the end of a line: a space would not be typeset here, but what about this dot?)